# Resources for Development Using DirectX in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics, resources, directx

Could some one provide me some good resources for development using DirectX in C#?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384561/managed-direct3d-or-xna-for-non-game-related-3d-graphics-programming#384723

Answer (score 2):

There is an old port of DirectX on C# in DirectX SDK from MS.

Also there is an open-source framework called SlimDX: http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft's XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) uses DirectX, it is designed to make DirectX/Game programming easier for managed developers.

Answer (score 1):

If DirectX is not strictly required, I encourage you to try [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/). It is graphics engine that built on top of DirectX or OpenGL. The library is originally in C++ but the [MOgre C# wrapper](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/MOGRE) is working fine. And it is easy to get started.