# Looking for a simple .Net, 3D drawing API (assembly)

Tags: .net, powerbuilder

I am looking for a simple 3D drawing API for .net. The shapes I need to draw are:

Hollow Cylinders
Hollow Spheres
Hollow Cubes
3D lines
3D text to annotate the shapes

The functionality I am looking for is basic pan, rotate and zoom capabilities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this thread for some other 3D options for .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384561/managed-direct3d-or-xna-for-non-game-related-3d-graphics-programming

Comment: What does PowerBuilder have to do with .NET?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at WPF (window Presentation Foundation, XAML)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much. I have looked at it and have drawn some basic shapes. I am hoping that there is an API that I can use in layer above WPF to do the drawing.

Comment: Any API you are going to find is probably just an abstraction of the WPF. You will probably do yourself a better service by just learning WPF and XAML. In doing so you will also learn Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the list the library from [Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/3d/)

There are some pre-packaged objects, such as a HollowCylinderMesh, various sphere and box objects, and teapots.  Might be worth a look if only to see how they are coded.